# How to iterate through selected rows in pandas dataframe with conditions matching three rows?

Tags: python, pandas

if I have a sample dataframe like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> a = [100,300,200,100,700,600,400,600]
>>> i =  ["2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007"]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(a, index = i, columns = {"gdp"})
>>> df
      gdp
2000  100
2001  300
2002  200
2003  100
2004  700
2005  600
2006  400
2007  600

res=[]
```

I want to iterate through the rows, and the conditions are: 
if row(x+1) - row(x) <0 & row (x+2)-row(x+1)<0
res.append(index[x])

So in this example, I would get a list of [2001, 2004]

I'm not sure how to write the code for this. Thank you!

Comment: y is it year 2002  not included? it gives a -ve too

Comment: @sammywemmy In your case  row (x+2)-row(x+1)>0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer non loop solution, because better performance - use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html), subtract by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) and compare with [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for less, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), if need also filter by column name `gdp`:

```
s1 = df['gdp'].shift(-1)
s2 = df['gdp'].shift(-2)

m = s1.sub(df['gdp']).lt(0) & s2.sub(s1).lt(0)
out = df.loc[m, 'gdp']
print (out)
2001    300
2004    700
Name: gdp, dtype: int64
```